# material ui : selectfiled multiple property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui, and I want to use the mutliple property, but I have an error : 
`multiple does not exist on the type selectfiled`

```
<SelectField
    multiple={true} //it doesn't work        
    value={this.state.valueProfession}
    onChange={this.handleChangeProfession}></SelectField>
```

I have the version `0.16.5` of material ui. I would like to avoid to update the last version of material ui. Is there other solution ? Thank you

Comment: actually the multiple Select Field feature is available starting from 0.17.1. I don't think it's much of work to upgrade your current version to 0.17.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your version 0.16.5 to newer version in order to use this.
I've used this in version  0.18.4

Here is the simple working example

```js
import React from 'react';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const names = [
    'Oliver Hansen',
    'Van Henry',
    'April Tucker',
    'Ralph Hubbard',
    'Omar Alexander',
    'Carlos Abbott',
    'Miriam Wagner',
    'Bradley Wilkerson',
    'Virginia Andrews',
    'Kelly Snyder',
];

/**
 * `SelectField` can handle multiple selections. It is enabled with the `multiple` property.
 */
export default class SelectFieldExampleMultiSelect extends React.Component {
    state = {
        values: [],
    };

    handleChange = (event, index, values) => this.setState({values});

    menuItems(values) {
        return names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem
                key={name}
                insetChildren={true}
                checked={values && values.indexOf(name) > -1}
                value={name}
                primaryText={name}
            />
        ));
    }

    render() {
        const {values} = this.state;
        return (
            <SelectField
                multiple={true}
                hintText="Select a name"
                value={values}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
                {this.menuItems(values)}
            </SelectField>
        );
    }
}
```